# How to update only a specific key of a nested document in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I have very little experience with MongoDB, and am having a hard time finding the answer I need in the docs.

Consider this document:

```js
{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "value3",
    key4: "value4"
  }
}
```

I am taking in an update object from an API endpoint that is only supplying the fields that it wants to update.  It could be any or all of the properties, but I don't know ahead of time what properties are going to be updated.

So how do I achieve the update to this document for the following scenarios:

```js
// THIS UPDATE
{
  key1: "update1",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "update3",
  }
}

// SETS THE DOC TO
{
  key1: "update1",
  key2: "value2",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "update3",
    key4: "value4"
  }
}

// THIS UPDATE
{
  nestedObject: {
    key4: "update4"
  }
}

// SETS THE DOC TO
{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "value3",
    key4: "update4"
  }
}

// THIS UPDATE
{
  key1: "update1",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "update3",
    key4: "update4"
  }
}

// SETS THE DOC TO
{
  key1: "update1",
  key2: "value2",
  nestedObject: {
    key3: "update3",
    key4: "update4"
  }
}
```

I understand the `$set` operator can set these nested fields, but it seems like that can only work if I know what specific key I need to update.  There's got to be a simple concept to deal with common scenarios like this that I'm not understanding because my experience is limited and I don't know the right search terms.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic way to update the fields for arbitrary levels of nesting. However, if you have a fixed nesting, you may use `$mergeObjects` to wrangle the documents. [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uldZCY-LItr)

Comment: @ray Seems like then I would need to know the values that exist in the document before the update?

Comment: It's more about the nesting. The `$mergeObjects` seems cannot do nested merging. If you do not  need to update the nestedObject, the `$mergeObjects` should be good to go